# assigning function to variable and using in parameter does not work

Tags: javascript

I am creating a rock paper scissors game for the 'Odin Project'. The instructions state to create a one round game with the computer selection randomized by using outside functions to implement in the one round function.

For practice, I am trying to assign a function to the variable name 'computerChoice'. When I do this it results as undefined. If I just use the function call 'computerPlay()' to put my parameter for playRound() it works. If I use the assigned variable for the function 'computerChoice' it does not work.

I googled this online and supposedly you are able to do this in Javascript. What am I doing wrong here?

```
let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
const rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
const computer = choices[rdm];
// let playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {


    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return 'It is a tie!!!';
    } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        return 'PAPER BEATS ROCK! computer wins!'
    } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        return 'ROCK BEATS SCISSORS! player wins!';
    } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        return 'SCISSORS BEATS PAPER! computer wins!'
    } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        return 'PAPER BEATS ROCK! player wins!';
    } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
        return 'ROCK BEATS SCISSORS! computer wins!'
    } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        return 'SCISSORS BEATS PAPER! player wins!';
    }

}




// function computerPlay() {
//     const computer = choices[rdm];
//     return computer;
// }

// console.log(playRound('rock', computerPlay())); // This works!

let computerChoice = function computerPlay() {
    const computer = choices[rdm];
    return computer;
}

console.log(playRound('rock', computerChoice)); // This does not Work!
```

Comment: I think you should invoke computer Choice function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you're trying to give your function two names:

```
let computerChoice = function computerPlay() {
  //...
}
```

Just the variable name will suffice:

```
let computerChoice = function () {
  //...
}
```

Aside from that, you're never executing the function.  You're successfully passing it to the `playRound` function, but then you just try to compare it:

```
if (playerSelection === computerSelection)
```

The first variable there is a string, and the second is a function.  They will never be equal.  It looks like you meant to execute it and pass its *result* to `playRound`:

```
console.log(playRound('rock', computerChoice()));
```

Alternatively, you'd have to execute it *within* `playRound`.  Perhaps something like:

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let computerSelectionResult = computerSelection();

  if (playerSelection === computerSelectionResult) {
    //...
  }
}
```